# Using Components with Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt and having issues importing components.

```
components/Header.vue
<template>
<h1>Header</h1>
</template>
```

```
index.vue
<template>
  <Header />
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header';
export default {
  components: {
    Header
  }
};
</script>
```

Replace the @ with ~ but did not change anything

This is the error I am getting.

@/components/Header in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/buyer/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/components/Header

Comment: Is this an eslint error or an error at build time?

Comment: It's a build time error. I've encoutered this once but I don't know how I solved it. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error from this example.